# Is the Conjunction of a necessary condition with a sufficient condition, a necessary and sufficient condition?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I came across a question where i had to find the necessary and sufficient condition for a property $p$. So i thought of finding a necessary condition $n$ and a sufficient condition $s$ separately and then putting a conjunction between them. But I'm not sure whether that would give me the necessary and sufficient condition. I'm not able to think of a counter example to this at the moment.
Formally my query is,

Are the sequents $(p\Rightarrow n) \land (s\Rightarrow p) \vdash (n\land s) \Leftrightarrow p$ and $(n\land s) \Leftrightarrow p\vdash (p\Rightarrow n) \land (s\Rightarrow p)$ valid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, because the sufficient property could be false: if $n=p=\top,s=\bot$, then $p⇒ n$ and $s⇒p$ are both true, but $n\wedge s=\bot$ while $p$ remains true, so the equivalence certainly cannot hold.

One could see that on an intuitive level by noting that since $s\implies p\implies n$, the statement $s\wedge n$ only depends on the statement of the stronger of both, namely the sufficient condition $s$. But that would reduce the right side to $s\Leftrightarrow p$, which is absurd in general.

Comment: Oh i see now, any false statement will be a sufficient condition for my property!